# Passing Objects from twig to Symfony Controller

Tags: symfony, twig

i have the following problem.

I generate an object in a symfony controller.
This object is passing to a twig template.
This works perfect.

But now i need to pass this object back to another controller.
How do i do that?

This object is an entity from a database. So i think i doesn't work to pass this object through a route as parameter.

Here i try to pass this object from a twig template:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('save', {'id': id, 'myObject': myObject}) }}">
```

i want to pass the id as route parameter, but not myObject.
So how can i get myObject in my controller?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is the following:

**Controller**

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use YourBundle\YourEntity;

/**
 * @Route("/your-entity/{id}/save/", name="save")
 */
public function saveAction(YourEntity $entity)
{
}
```

**template**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('save', {'id': myObject.id}) }}">
```

This will automatically load the object from the database by the id value, or throw a 404 when the object is not found

Comment: The problem is, that i want to save this object. It doesn't exists in the database at this time.

Comment: In that case you should use this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html